# Why can I close my own question?

Tags: discussion, closing

While I know closing questions is supposed to be done by the community to encourage higher-quality questions, I also have the option to close my **own** question.

See the following:

[image: Closing own questions]

This is how it would look like (just as normal):

[image: Closing menu]

Does this have any use? Why is it possible?

Comment: for closing as a dupe?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thats one of the options I’d have; I’d also have the options ‘community specific reason’ ‘needs details’ ‘needs focus’ or ‘opinion based’

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163375/196432

Comment: You have a problem you want to solve. You check this website and don't find an answer, so you decide to write a question. Afterwards, somebody finds an answer to your question in a different post and casts a "Close"-request. You acknowledge that the other post indeed solves your question but you just cannot imagine how to find that other post, based on your search criteria. So you add your own "Close"-vote, referring to the same post, you have helped declared your question as being a duplicate but with easier search arguments.